# How to encrypt connection to SQL Server in Node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, ssl, encryption

I am using the mssql client for node.js to connect to SQL Server 2014. This is working great, however there is now a new requirement to use the highest level encryption (TLS 1.2) for communications to all databases. The only documentation I am able to find on encrypted connection to SQL Server in Node.js is the encrypt:true property of the connection options which is designated for Azure connections.  This is an on-premise database, when i do set encrypt:true the connection just stalls. No error, just does not successfully connect. Any help with direction on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am using mssql client which by default uses Tedious driver.  I am wrapping this with sequelize ORM, setting the dialect to mssql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some testing with MSSQL driver, I was able to successfully connect to SQL Server 2014 over TLS 1.2 by having our DBA's force encryption at the database and require TLS 1.2, then adding the encrypt:true property to the connection options.  Our production app has an ORM layer through Sequelize so using the native MSSQL under the hood, I added

```
dialectOptions {
    encrypt: true
}
```

to the Sequelize connection object and tada

Comment: Will this approach work even if I do not use Sequelize?

Comment: Yes.  In the scenario above using Sequelize, dialectOptions simply tells sequelize to pass the property settings directly to the underlying client.  In my case it was MSSQL.  If you are using node to connect to SQL Server, it would be unadvisable to use anything but MSSQL (which uses Tedious as its driver) since other SQL Server clients like Microsofts node-sqlserver are either underdeveloped or completely abandoned.

If you're using MSSQL directly (which is a fine idea, I just wanted another layer of abstraction) you would simply pass the option like this:

options {
    encrypt: true
}